# How to change the order of string values in column python?

Tags: pandas, string

I have a few columns in the **df** out of which I want to change the format of this column called **a**,

```
a
2019 Sep WK 1
2019 Sep WK 1
2019 Sep WK 2
2020 Sep WK 2
2020 Sep WK 2
2020 Sep WK 3
```

I want the final column to look like the following,

```
a_final
Sep-19
Sep-19
Sep-19
Sep-20
Sep-20
Sep-20
```

I found a function to do this using python but I dont know how to implement this as dataframe function,

```
def change_order(string, split_char, *args):
string = string.split(split_char)

new_list = []

for i in args:
    try:
        new_list.append(string[i])  # change to i-1 for abstracted parameters
    except IndexError:
        return False

return split_char.join(new_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    input = '2019 Sep WK 1'
    print (change_order(input, ' ', 1, 0))
```

Is there a better and easier way to implement this using pandas library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexing for selecting letters like:

```
df['new'] = df['a'].str[5:8] + '-' + df['a'].str[2:4]
print (df)
               a     new
0  2019 Sep WK 1  Sep-19
1  2019 Sep WK 1  Sep-19
2  2019 Sep WK 2  Sep-19
3  2020 Sep WK 2  Sep-20
4  2020 Sep WK 2  Sep-20
5  2020 Sep WK 3  Sep-20
```

If need working with splitted values first `str[0]` select first list from `splitted` and second `.str[-2:]` return last 2 years values:

```
splitted = df['a'].str.split()
df['new'] = splitted.str[1] + '-' + splitted.str[0].str[-2:]
```